# Routing considerations for a commercial flight from Brisbane to Vietnam

Tags: vietnam, brisbane

There are no direct commercial flights from Brisbane to Vietnam.

It seems like connecting through Singapore is the most common routing.

However, there are other routes.

Any suggestions? What are the considerations for common, reasonable routes?

Comment: This is too localized, few people care about this specific route. However, you should check our questions about booking flights: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9980/low-cost-airlines-search-engine http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/any-travel-booking-sites-that-let-you-search-for-a-mixed-itinerary (last to know where you can have a layover).

Comment: a) this is price-shopping, which is out-of-scope for this SE. b) cheapest AND fastest is always a contradiction in travel. Pick one.

Comment: You might be better off flying to the Gold Coast and taking a train/bus up to Brisbane. Quite a few lower cost Asian carriers use the Gold Coast airport

Comment: Cheapest is hitchhiking (yes, it is possible), but as other commentators have said, it's price-shopping in its current form. Please edit if you have a question that fits the [help] and we'll be happy to answer, but as it is it'll likely get closed.

Comment: Fastest is probably to ring up Netjets, and charter your own private jet for the journey! (If you meant to restrict it to scheduled services, you'd best add that to the question...)

Comment: I disagree that the problem is that it's localized. Stack Exchange has dropped the notion of "too localized" as a close reason. It isn't a suitable question however but the problem is that it doesn't "have one right answer". It's a forum question asking for various opinions and thoughts. Stack Exchange is about answers, not discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other major hub that normally serves Vietnam is Bangkok (I wouldn't recommend flying to ICN or NRT from Brisbane). I found for my flights Bangkok is slightly more expensive to fly to, but overnight lodging is less expensive than Singapore.

I have seen flights from Vietnam to Phnom Penh and Siam Reap (I assume there are flights in the opposite direction), but I suspect they will be more expensive than Bangkok due to a smaller supply of flights.

If you stay the night then connecting through Singapore or Bangkok are probably about the same. If you only have a brief layover I would go through Singapore.